# JavaScript - Displaying different fieldsets in same area depending on event

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have 3 separate fieldsets two(B & C) containing forms and one(A) containing a list. Fieldset A will be located on the left and there will be a designated location to the right for fieldset B and C.

What is clicked in fieldset A will determine which fieldset will be displayed.
So if I click list item 1 on A,  B will appear on the right. If i click list item 2, C will replace B.

I'm not concerned with the CSS currently, I would just like to display the corresponding fieldset when the li is selected.

I'm confused on how to actually accomplish this. I've played around with the idea of using a display function in php and depending on what is selected calling that function. However, I feel like this is more of a JavaScript thing. Ideally, it would be nice to have a JavaScript function that will display the HTML structure. So when the li is clicked, that function will be called. However, I'm very new to JavaScript and my attempts at this have yet to work.  Am I even on the right track to accomplishing this? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

my code:

```html
<fieldset >
 <legend>A</legend>
  <ul>
  <li onclick ="displayB();">List Item 1</li>
  <li onclick ="displayC();">List Item 2</li>
  </ul>
  </fieldset>

<script>
function displayB(){ </script>
 <fieldset>
 <legend>B</legend>
  <form method="post" action="index.php">
   <label>Input 1&nbsp;</label>
   <input type="text" size="20">
   <br>
   <label>Input 2&nbsp;</label>
   <input type="text" size="20">
   <br>      
   <input type="submit" value="Add" />
  </form>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td></td><td>Input</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
  <td><button>X</button></td><td>Input 1</td>
  </tr>
  </table>     
 </fieldset>
   
<script> }   
function displayC(){ </script>
 <fieldset>
 <legend>C</legend>
  <form method="post" action="index.php">
   <label>Input 1&nbsp;</label>
   <input type="text" size="20">
   <br>
   <label>Input 2&nbsp;</label>
   <input type="text" size="20">
   <br>      
   <select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
   </select>
  </form>
  <input style="float:right;" type="submit" value="Edit" />    
 </fieldset>
<script> } </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind having the HTML for both in the DOM you can do this:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bw87qbns/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>A</legend>
        <ul>
        <li onclick ="displayFieldsets('B', 'C');">List Item 1</li>
        <li onclick ="displayFieldsets('C', 'B');">List Item 2</li>
        </ul>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <fieldset id="B">
    <legend>B</legend>
        <form method="post" action="index.php">
            <label>Input 1&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="text" size="20">
            <br>
            <label>Input 2&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="text" size="20">
            <br>                        
            <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </form>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td></td><td>IP</td><td>Zone</td><td>Input)</td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
        <td><button>X</button></td><td>Input 1</td>
        </tr>
        </table>                    
    </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="C">
    <legend>C</legend>
        <form method="post" action="index.php">
            <label>Input 1&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="text" size="20">
            <br>
            <label>Input 2&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="text" size="20">
            <br>                        
            <select>
                <option>Option 1</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <input style="float:right;" type="submit" value="Edit" />               
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function displayFieldsets (id1, id2) {
    document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'none';
}
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#B, #C {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to only insert the HTML when they are needed I can show you how to change this to do that. Let me know! =]

EDIT: As noted in comment another way to do it using only CSS classes: http://jsfiddle.net/bw87qbns/1/

Comment: This is absolutely perfect! Is there a specific reason I would rather just display the HTML? I don't mind this way, I'm just curious as to the difference and the pros and cons of both and how that would actually work. Thank you so much!

Comment: No I don't think there is a real reason not to have it there but hidden. Some people just have certain criteria. From your question neither of those elements existed until they were needed so I was just checking since my answer changed the way you had originally envisioned the scenario. I think having what you need available is fine for most cases.

Comment: Possibly cleaner alternative: set a CSS class and let the CSS show/hide the fieldset

Comment: Okay, I greatly appreciate it, Thank you for your time and help!!

Comment: @JuanMendes Correct! Many solutions to this problem.

Comment: Added another fiddle demonstrating how to do it using classes to hide and show

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't mix JavaScript and HTML like that.

Here's a pure CSS solution.  It uses hidden `input` elements.  When their `label`s are clicked, the appropriate `fieldset` displays.

```css
fieldset:first-of-type {
  display: block;
}

fieldset {
  display: none;
}

#IB, #IC {
  display: none;
}

#IB:checked ~ fieldset.B {
  display: block;
}

#IC:checked ~ fieldset.C {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>A</legend>
  <ul>
    <li><label for="IB">List Item 1</label></li>
    <li><label for="IC">List Item 2</label></li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>

<input id="IB" name="field" type="radio"></input>
<input id="IC" name="field" type="radio"></input>

<fieldset class="B">
  <legend>B</legend>
  <form method="post" action="index.php">
    <label>Input 1&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="text" size="20">
    <br>
    <label>Input 2&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="text" size="20">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
  </form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Input</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button>X</button>
      </td>
      <td>Input 1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="C">
  <legend>C</legend>
  <form method="post" action="index.php">
    <label>Input 1&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="text" size="20">
    <br>
    <label>Input 2&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="text" size="20">
    <br>
    <select>
      <option>Option 1</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <input style="float:right;" type="submit" value="Edit" />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you so much for the alternative solution to the problem. I was unaware if they could be used like that. Thank you!